# Bug for Cubics -> True in Eigenvalues?

Tags: bugs, linear-algebra, options, eigenvalues

Let's consider the simple code

```
Eigenvalues[{{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}, {g, h, i}}, Cubics -> True]
(* {Root[<<1>> &, 1],Root[<<1>> &, 2],Root[<<1>> &, 3]} *)
```

Using the option `Cubics -> True`, I expected the `Root[]` expressed in terms of radicals. Why it's not the case?

The same happens considering a 4 by 4 matrix and the option `Quartics -> True`.

P. S.
I know that I can use `ToRadicals` but my question is about the options `Cubics` and `Quartics` that seem do not have any effect for `Eigenvalues`.

Comment: What version are you on? `Eigenvalues[{{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}, {g, h, i}}, Cubics -> True]` yields explicit radicals in 11.2.

Comment: I'm using version 11.2 on Linux x86

Comment: Weird. It happens on a 32-bit kernel but not 64. I'll report it as a bug.

Comment: Works on Raspberry Pi too (v11.0.1, 32-bit, ARM)